# What is this query doing?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following tables:

```
PRODUCT ( ProdId, Name, Price, Weight, Category, Description, … )
DETAIL ( OrdId, ProdId, Qty, … )
ORDER ( OrdId, ClientId, Amount, OrdDate, DeliveryDate, ChosenStoreId, … )
```

and I must describe in simple words (i.e. to a non programmer), what the following query is doing:

```
select * from Order O
where Amount < 0.95 * ( select sum( Qty * Price ) from Product natural join Detail
where OrderId = O.OrderId )
```

My initial response was that it was showing the orders with the lowest amounts, which is only  5% of them, but it was marked as incorrect.

Another thought I had was perhaps it represented a discount, however the exercise description does not mention anything about discounts so I'm guessing it's also incorrect.

Can anyone tell me what the query is doing? Thanks in advance.

Note: apart from the tables, this is all the relevant information I have for the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re Gordon I also don't approve of `natural join`. The query seems intentionally cryptic, especially since there's no example data. A good strategy is to write out the SQL in more general syntax and infer, see below:

```
select o.OrdId,
       sum(o.Amount) Amount,
       sum(d.Qty * p.Price) QtyPrice

from Order as o
  left join Detail as d on d.OrdId = o.OrdId
  left join Product as p on p.ProdId = d.ProdId

group by o.OrdId

having sum(o.Amount) < (0.95 * sum(d.Qty * p.Price))
```

To me, this query returns

1. All unique orders made in a system
2. Where the amount charged on the order was LESS than 95% of the expected amount.

Like you said, this could be a discount tracker, or maybe the `o.Amount` field is populated independently of the `Detail` and `Product` tables and this shows any errors.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering. Would you mind telling me why natural joins are not good?

Comment: Readability is the main reason. Maybe you want to only include matching records, thus using `inner join`. Or perhaps you need to see `null` values between two tables, so you use `left join`. Joins are huge, and their usage greatly affects the query output. Using `natural join` masks that intent, making it harder for you and others to debug the code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't approve of `natural join`, but that is a separate issue.

This is returning rows where the `amount` of the order is less than 95% of the sum of the prices of the items on the order.

The cause for the difference is unclear -- it could be due to discounts at the `order` level; it could be due to extra charges, such as taxes or shipping; or there could be other causes as well.